# Measuring time in android browser in microseconds

Tags: javascript, android, browser, time

I want to measure the time it takes for a javascript method to execute in an Android web application. Unfortunately Date.now() does not work since measuring in milliseconds is too inaccurate. To my knowledge performance.now() does not work in the Android browser.

Is there any way to get the current time in microseconds in javascript in the android browser?

This is my usage scenario:

```
function measure_time(){
   var start = Date.now();
   ....do something....
   var end = Date.now();
   alert(end-start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply loop the script you want to test 1000 times and then divide the outcome by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

call `System.nanoTime()` when you start and stop.  Note that `System.nanoTime()` has precision, but not accuracy, so it's most likely not synced up to the world clock in real time but still useful for measuring how long something took to do.  Divide the result by 1000 to get the number in microseconds

Comment: No, I did not know I had to do that :P How do I do that in javascript?